# Prestashop error 503 when importing large csv file

Tags: prestashop, php-7.2

I'm importing a large csv file (arround 30k lines) with the native importer of Prestashop (1.7.6.7) but i crashes (most often after the data validation).

I'm running my web server with apache and php fpm 7.2. Here are the logd i get :

```
Jun 25 10:00:01.490369 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 18083:tid 139680320476928] [client 176.141.207.46:63302] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: https://preprod.motogoodeal.ch/admin5473ukqbi/index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=bf736a3ca6f1406cf822f2dd9c22f028
[Fri Jun 25 10:00:01.490404 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 18083:tid 139680320476928] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 176.141.207.46:63302] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : , referer: https://preprod.motogoodeal.ch/admin5473ukqbi/index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=bf736a3ca6f1406cf822f2dd9c22f028
```

It worked before

Comment: The error is probably because of the PHP code sending an incorrect response.

Comment: I'm getting this message on front : 

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this issue in a development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by increasing the pm.max_children value :)

Answer (score 1):

Pls check PHP Parameters with your host provider such as :
allow_url_fopen = On

allow_url_include = Off

asp_tags = Off

display_errors = Off

enable_dl = Off

file_uploads = On

max_execution_time = 30

max_input_time = 60

max_input_vars = 50000

memory_limit = 512M

session.save_path = ""

upload_max_filesize = 128M

but you need input the right value for each one based on your needs and hosting's resources